# How to pass data from flask to html file continuously?

Tags: python, html, flask

I have script which executes for 10 minutes and generates logs/outputs while executing..i want these logs to be passed to html file using flask.

Comment: what is the problem ?
what have you tried ?
do you mean *continuously* as in real-time or as in *periodically* ?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I mean the data-should be updated in real time.

Answer (score 3):

1. You can use ajax methods in your javascript code to ask server for new logs/outputs with any period.
2. You can open WebSocket and write your logs to client in real-time. Look at example on flask-socketIO documentation: https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ or somewhere else.
   Here is example how to send message to client:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, send

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@socketio.on('message')
def handle_message(message):
    send(message)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

Comment: Can you give me an example how to use ajax to ask server for new logs/outputs.

Comment: Check out first answer in original question. There you can find an example.